# How to make grid stretch across whole html page in twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter, twitter-bootstrap

Building a home page and I want the grid to stretch across the whole page. I tried setting the containers width at 100 percent but it seems not to be working. I am working with a the default grid system. An example of what i am looking for is www.rdio.com.

```
<div class="container">

   <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

     <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="active item"><img src="/site_media/static/img/" /></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="/site_media/static/img/ /> </div>
        <div class="item"><img src="/site_media/static/img/ /> </div>
     </div>
```

‹
          ›

```
   </div>

  <div class="row" id= "middleRow">

     <div class="span4" id="explanation"> </div>

     <div class="span4" id="explanation"> </div>

     <div class="span4" id="explanation"> </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Show your code. We have no idea what you've done if you don't show it. And link doesn't tell much of what you looking for. Describe your problem more in depth.

Comment: Agreed; we need to see what you're working with. Are you using a fluid grid, a fixed grid, are you using CSS or LESS, etc. Have you tried a solution and failed? If so, what have you tried?

Comment: Alrighty, I am using a fixed grid default layout, im using LESS, and my solution was to make the container 100% but that did not work. here is my code.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you look at the scaffolding on bootstraps website you'll see that

```
<div class="container-fluid">
```

is the container to use to make it go across the whole website.

you can also do this with rows like

```
<div class="row-fluid">
```

hope that helps

here's the link
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html